# crash report solving?

Tags: iphone

i used the utility **symbolicatecrash** as mentioned in tutorial ..

```
  $ symbolicatecrash report.crash MobileLines.app.dSYM > report-with-symbols.crash
```

it produces report with symbols, as i am new to this,how can i use this report
to solve the crash?any help please?

Answer (score 2):

The crash log will tell you in which method the crash happened, what kind of exception occurred and how the method in question was called (via the stack trace). Hopefully, you should be able to deduct from this info what the user was doing when the crash happened. I would then try to reproduce it myself. If you can't reproduce the problem, it is going to be very hard to debug because you won't be able to tell if you fixed it.